# Virtualbox: connect diff host-only networks?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Say, I have 2 guest machines. One is in network vboxnet1(IP: `192.168.59.1` mask: `255.255.255.0`). Another is in network vboxnet2(IP: `192.168.60.1` mask: `255.255.255.0`). Both machines could reach the host in each host-only network. It is possible to connect these 2 networks such that machines in vboxnet1 could reach machines in vboxnet2? You may have other ways to do this using other configuration alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT after discussion in comments:

Connecting the two Host-Only Networks would require a router;  a third VM can be connected to the two networks and configured as a router.

..

However, you don't need to connect the host-only networks.
Guest machines can be connected with an **Internal Network**:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal

## Instructions:

### 1) DHCP server.

Setup a VirtualBox DHCP server using the following command:

```
vboxmanage dhcpserver add --netname intnet --ip 10.10.10.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0 --lowerip 10.10.10.2 --upperip 10.10.10.10 --enable
```

All IP address values can be changed as needed.

The `--netname` specified MUST be used in the configuration of the VMs' network adapters.

### 2) Set up an Internal Network Adapter per VM.

For each VM, you need to create a Network Adapter:

1. In each machine's settings, go to Network,
2. Enable a Network Adapter, and select **"Attached to" : "Internal Network"**,
3. Set the Name to the same as the `netname` given to the DHCP server.

### 3) Bootup Virtual Machines!

Once bootup up, use `ifconfig` command to check that a new adapter is available with an IP address in the range of `lowerup` and `upperup` specified in the DHCP server above.

That's it, the machines are now connected.

Comment: the question could be rephrased to: is there some ways to let one guest in network A reach another guest in network B in virtualbox? Your answer is based on DHCP. From your example, a guest could gain one IP ranging from 10.10.10.2 to 10.10.10.10, which is in the same network.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear... I read this "other ways to do this using other configuration" and thought you just want any method to connect different machines.

Comment: To connect two **different networks**, one way is... Create a THIRD machine, connected to the two host-only networks.  This third machine can then be configured as a router.  But, why would you want to do this?

Comment: sorry. I just wonder whether there are some ways to do that without router

Comment: To my knowledge, no.  There is no other way.  Someone else might know more than I do.

Comment: You can not connect to another network without a router. What you could do without any additional setup in VirtualBox (except the part with the NAT network) - if you setup a second vNIC connected to the VirtualBox NAT Network you will be able to connect from the VM with two vNICs (NAT & Host Only #1) to the other VM with the Host Only #2 but not vice versa (here the NAT Network will route the traffic). Just tested it.

Comment: @JACKM, connecting two networks is exactly what a router _does_. That said, the host itself could very well be the router; no need for a dedicated VM.